# Expected Declaration Error

Tags: ios, swift, declaration, object-expected

My problem is that I tried make a calculator but I didn't do this because of expected declaration problem. I examined other questions about expected declaration but I didn't fix this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Screen: UILabel!
    var firstNumber = Int()
    var secondNumber = Int()
    var isTypingNumber = false
    var result = Int()
    var operation = ""


    @IBAction func number(sender: AnyObject) {
        let number = sender.currentTitle
        if isTypingNumber == true {
            Screen.text =   Screen.text! + number!!
        } else {
            Screen.text = number;
        }
        isTypingNumber = true


    }


    @IBAction func operation(sender: AnyObject) {
        isTypingNumber = false
        firstNumber = Int(Screen.text!)!
        operation = sender.currentTitle!!

    }

    @IBAction func equals(sender: AnyObject) {
        secondNumber = Int(Screen.text!)!
        if operation == "+" {
            result = firstNumber + secondNumber
        } else if operation == "-" {
            result = firstNumber - secondNumber
        } else if operation == "x" {
            result = firstNumber * secondNumber

        }else {
            result = firstNumber / secondNumber

        }
        Screen.text = "\(result)"

        func clear(sender: AnyObject) {
            firstNumber = 0
            secondNumber = 0
            isTypingNumber = false
            result = 0
            Screen.text = "\(result)"

        }





        func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

}
```

Comment: `var x = int()` is wrong.... It has to look like this: `var firstNumber: Int?`
The ? makes the var Optional so it can be nil. If you don't make it optional you have to set the variable while declaring it. `var noOptional: Int = 0`

Comment: @Godlike actually `var x = Int()` will compile, it will initialize x to `0`.

Comment: @JAL really? Oh I tested it and you are right. So it has to be sth. else

Comment: @Godlike it's a syntax error, see my answer.

Comment: @JAL yep I saw it and voted it up. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as a "simple typographical error."  If my answer did not solve your issue, please feel free to follow up with additional information by editing it into your question.  If my answer did help you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace in your `equals` function:

```
@IBAction func equals(sender: AnyObject) {
    secondNumber = Int(Screen.text!)!
    if operation == "+" {
        result = firstNumber + secondNumber
    } else if operation == "-" {
        result = firstNumber - secondNumber
    } else if operation == "x" {
        result = firstNumber * secondNumber

    }else {
        result = firstNumber / secondNumber

    }
    Screen.text = "\(result)"
} // missing this
```